# Haskell Conditionals

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements

I'm having some difficulty integrating && within Guards eg:

```
something :: Char -> Int
something k 
 | ord k >= 77 && ord k <= 98 = 8
 | otherwise = 88
```

How the heck can i achieve the above without setting off an error?

Cheers.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: *sigh* It appears that my error had nothing at all to do with && clashing with the guard at all, but a simple Hugs-line typo (forgot to add ' to the end) i made - This was my first post, so please forgive me guys.

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, an identifier starting with an uppercase letter designates a type, whereas a function name has to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Just a silly typo i made when i wrote the example, that mistake is not there in my actual code. How can write && within Guards mmarxs?? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Apart from the uppercase `Something`, there's nothing wrong with that snippet. If you haven't already done so, you'll need to import `ord` from the `Char` module.

Comment: Darn, it appearns my example is too simple to set off the error my actual code set's off...please give me a moment guys while i type in my actual code.

Comment: An identifier starting with an Uppercase letter (`:` too) can also designate a data constructor.